# How to get drive distance polygon with ServiceAreaTask?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, arcgis-online, service-area

I'm using an ArcGIS Online ServiceAreaTask to calculate drive-distance polygons.
In the ServiceAreaParameters that I pass to ServiceAreaTask.solve(), there is an attribute named impedanceAttribute.
In the API reference, it's explained that this attribute can take "Time" or "Length" as value: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/serviceareaparameters-amd.html#impedanceattribute

When I switch between Time and Length, I get exacly the same polygons. I guess that impedence attribute isn't taken into consideration by the task.

I'm using ArcGIS Javascript API and ArcGIS Online services. So, I have no access to the Network.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using this network service? http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Network/USA/NAServer/Service%20Area

Comment: You're using ServiceArea task from ArcGIS Online, right? I'd take a look at this doc, specific to that service: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Service_Area_service_with_synchronous_execution/02r3000000n2000000/   Or are you indeed using it against your own network service layer from ArcGIS Server?

Comment: I'm using this ArcGIS Online service: http://route.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/ServiceAreas/NAServer/ServiceArea_World?token=<the_token>

@KHibma In the help page you provided, it's said, impedanceAttribute can take "Kilometers" or "Miles" as values for travel distance areas. I tried that but it's not different from travel-time areas.

Comment: Even when I change travelMode attribute, nothing happens!

Comment: Did you read the note on travelMode -- you need to use the itemID:   The travel mode parameter requires an alphanumeric code, or item ID, to be passed in rather than a travel-mode name. The item ID values of the service will change over time, so it is important to include the following look-up logic in your applications:

Comment: Yes I used itemID like described in the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the jsapi documentation could be a little clearer on this point, but you need to supply whatever string that the particular service you are working with expects.  as mentioned in the [service documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcgis-rest-api/#/Service_Area_service_with_synchronous_execution/02r3000000n2000000/), acceptable values for imped**a**nceAttribute are

```
'TravelTime' (default)
'TruckTravelTime'
'WalkTime'
'Miles'
'Kilometers'
```

if you provide anything else, the service will ignore your value and use the default.

Comment: I used 'Kilometers' as value for impedenceAttribute and it didn't change anything!!

Comment: its 'impedance' not 'impedence'.  i've made the appropriate correction to my original answer for clarity.  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59331579/js/impedence-attribute.html